# How to remove duplicate data in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net

**Question:** How to remove duplicated data in crystal report and what are the causes of it?

Here's my codes

```
    Dim rpt As New PendingRequest
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet("DataSet1")




    Try
        con = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=123456;database=asset_db")
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  request_number,asset_name, asset_type, asset_price, asset_quantity, tbl_asset_maintenance.supplier_code, supplier_name , reason_to_buy from tbl_asset_request join tbl_asset_maintenance on tbl_asset_request.asset_number = tbl_asset_maintenance.asset_number  left join tbl_supplier on tbl_asset_maintenance.supplier_code = tbl_supplier.supplier_code  left join tbl_account_group on tbl_asset_maintenance.group_code = tbl_account_group.group_code where asset_request_num = " & account_payable_form.req_num & " order by request_number"
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl_asset_request")
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl_asset_maintenance")
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl_supplier")
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl_account_group")
        rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("root", "123456")
        rpt.Database.Tables(0).SetDataSource(ds)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: Maybe a select distinct...

Comment: I've tried it, sir but the output was the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have read Your Question the causes of this is in Your Join in Your commant text ,
You want to sure about each and every table that here LEFT join required or inner join requires...

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT request_number,asset_name, asset_type, asset_price, asset_quantity, tbl_asset_maintenance.supplier_code, supplier_name , reason_to_buy from tbl_asset_request tas,tbl_asset_maintenance tam,tbl_supplier ts,tbl_asset_maintenance tam,tbl_account_group
>   tag WHERE tas.asset_number = tam.asset_number and tam.supplier_code = ts.supplier_code and tam.group_code = tag.group_code where asset_request_num = " & account_payable_form.req_num & " order by request_number"

Try this in your command text and view result.